# javascript for loop to use a function for several objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops, for-loop

I am working on a game that has three dice cubes that show random faces upon clicking a button.
Images are by css image sprite. If the random number gets 1 the dice cube is assigned to a css class that has its image sprite.

```
function diceroll (){

    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * (6 - 1 + 1)) + 1;

        switch (randomnumber) {

        case 1:
            document.getElementById("dice1").setAttribute("class", "face1");
            break;
        case 2:
            document.getElementById("dice1").setAttribute("class", "face2");
            break;
        case 3:
            document.getElementById("dice1").setAttribute("class", "face3");
            break;
        case 4:
            document.getElementById("dice1").setAttribute("class", "face4");
            break;
        case 5:
            document.getElementById("dice1").setAttribute("class", "face5");
            break;
        case 6:
            document.getElementById("dice1").setAttribute("class", "face6");
            break;
    }
}
```

I have a separate button, when clicked it should run the above diceroll function to the three divs with ids dice1, dice2 and dice3.

I want to use

```
function gotoloop (){

    for (i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        // the code that affects dice(n) and n=1 and then diceroll function
        // affects dice1 n+1
    }

}
```

I researched and could not find a way to implement the code for the last commented two lines. Please let me know if my approach is correct and help me with the code.

Comment: People, please explain your down votes. The question might not be the best as the problem is easy, but it is written clearly and shows some work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correcly, you want something like this:

```
function diceroll (diceId){

    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    switch (randomnumber) {

        case 1:        document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face1");        break;
        case 2:        document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face2");        break;
        case 3:        document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face3");        break;
        case 4:        document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face4");        break;
        case 5:        document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face5");        break;
        case 6:        document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face6");        break;
    }
}

function gotoloop (){
    // Start loop at i=1 because the first ID is dice1
    for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
        // the code that affects dice(n) and n=1 and then diceroll function affects dice1
        // n+1
        diceroll("dice" + i);
    }
}
```

Or as per Marc Baumbach's comment, you could write:

```
function diceroll (diceId){

    var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;

    document.getElementById(diceId).setAttribute("class", "face" + randomnumber);
}
```

Comment: +1, I think this is what they meant. The `switch` could also be removed and simply append the random number to the `"face"` string. The code here `(6 - 1 + 1)` should probably just be `6` too. :)